# substitut for equalTo() method in jquery validate

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am using **jQuery Validate Plugin** now and have some problem with it.

My html:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="item">
        <span class="label"><b class="red">*</b>CardNo:</span>
        <input class="BankCardNo" name="BankCardNo" type="text" value=""/> 
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <span class="label"><b class="red">*</b>Confirm CardNo:</span>
        <input class="ConfirmCardNo" name="ConfirmCardNo" type="text" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <div class="item">
        <span class="label"><b class="red">*</b>CardNo:</span>
        <input class="BankCardNo" name="BankCardNo" type="text" value=""/> 
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <span class="label"><b class="red">*</b>Confirm CardNo:</span>
        <input class="ConfirmCardNo" name="ConfirmCardNo" type="text" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am making *Bankcard Manage Page*. one can add several cards at a time.

I want to make every card validate separately，
but `equalTo` method only accept element id,name,attr

such as

```
$("#myForm").validate({
  rules: {
    "Password": {
      required: true,
    },

    "ConfirmPassword": {
      required: true
      equalTo: '#Password'
    }
  },

  errorElement: "div"
});
```

this is validate plugin add rules, it's very beautiful.
so I just want all validation codes like this.
this is the main problem.

If I write code like below, it can't find the correct CardNo......

```
$('.card').find('.ConfirmCardNo').rules('add', {
  required: true,
  equalTo: '.CardNo'
});
```

how I achieve my purpose?

Comment: The only way I can image is to write a particular method to validate the card, but I just want to let validate use one plugin，use the format of jquery.validate

Comment: how to add multiple rule here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
var $elems = $('.card');

(function fetch(i) {
    if(i >= $elems.length) return;  // no elems left

    var $elem = $elems.eq(i);

    $($elem).find('.ConfirmCardNo').rules('add',{ 
        required:true, 
        equalTo:$($elem).find('.CardNo')
    });

    fetch(i + 1);  // next one

  })(0);  // start with first elem
```

or if you want to use only one plugin

you can loop through all the card div's and make rule based on their values

Comment: how are you adding multiple conditons here

Comment: why stackoverflow can't add code in comment box...... look here http://jsfiddle.net/ZUfwk/

Comment: I have tried it for a while ,it seems equalTo only accept string ....or maybe I have something wrong.I will try on it more, you give me a good hint ，thank you very much.

Comment: I find the flaw in my code, your method is great! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this ,like selector

```
$("#registerForm").validate({
    rules:{
        name:{
            required:true,
            email:true
        },
        password:{
            required:true,
            minlength:6,
            maxlength:12
        },
        cfmPassword:{

            equalTo:$('#registerForm').find('#password'),
            minlength:6,
            maxlength:12
        }

    },
    errorPlacement: function( error, element ) {
        error.insertAfter( element.parent() );
    }
});
```

Comment: when you want to use 'equalTo' rule, you must locate the target as the more precise the better